# FFMPEG Streaming updated image in loop to FB Live Video

Tags: facebook, video, ffmpeg, rtmp, live-streaming

I am trying to stream image to fb live video using this command :

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -re -i "input.jpg" -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v baseline -s 720x480 -bufsize 6000k -vb 400k -maxrate 1500k -deinterlace -t 60 -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -g 30 -r 30 -f flv "rtmp_link"`

This command works perfectly for one single input file. But the problem is that I want ffmpeg to stream the latest and updated version of "input.jpg" file because my app is updating this "input.jpg" after every 2-3 seconds but the image that is streamed is the older version, not the updated one.

If I try to restart this loop, then streaming stops for approx. 4-5 seconds which is sufficient enough for FB live video to consider that streaming has been stopped and it then ends the live video.

So, is it possible to use the latest available version of input file for streaming in this loop? I don't know much about FFMPEG and I tried to search this issue but all in vain.

Comment: Try answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41132358/5726027).

Comment: @Mulvya this didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally figured out a solution for this. When I was directly overwriting ‘input.jpg’ file using my rails app,  this process was taking a few miliseconds but during this time too, ffmpeg was streaming this file which was incomplete for few miliseconds.

So, the solution for this issue is that first write the updated image to a temp file like ‘input.tmp.img’ and then move this file to the original file using script or using terminal like 
`mv input.tmp.img input.jpg`
As moving process hardly takes any time, this solved the problem for me.

Comment: Probably the most simple solution. `mv` will do its job *atomically*: other processes will only see either the old or new file and not a partial file.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to add dynamic image overlay on live stream video input? Means we can keep changing image overlay after video stream started?

Comment: I had this challenge when I worked on more features on my project. Eventually, I had to start using selenium in headless mode and then use FFMPEG to do stream capture. 

That way, I had full control on what I'm showing on headless screen using HTML/CSS and JS.