# ffmpeg continuously stream refreshing image to rtmp

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

Is there a way to **stream** one image and **refresh** it all the time or at an interval.

This streams image continuously, but never refreshes its source.

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -i http://test.dev/overlay.jpg -f flv rtmp://192.168.99.100:1935/live/mystream2`

The overlay does the same, never refreshes logo...

`ffmpeg -i rtmp://192.168.99.100:1935/live/mystream -vf "movie=overlay.jpg[logo];
[0][logo]overlay=0:70" -c:v flv -f flv rtmp://192.168.99.100:1935/live/mystream2`

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with adding `-f image2`. Works with [PNGs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41132358/5726027).

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -loop 1 -i http://test.dev/overlay.jpg -f flv rtmp://192.168.99.100:1935/live/mystream2
```

Comment: Have you tried it with youtube?
I'm gettign no signal

Comment: Same here no signal at youtube.

Comment: @AlexPolymath Found the reason.
I tried this solution and after that I have created a Video without any sound and streamed it to youtube. But that didn't worked same as this one. The main problem is youtube stream expects a audio track with the video. You can create image with sound with this command `ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -f image2 -loop 1 -i image.png -r 15 -s 640x480 -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -tune stillimage -preset medium -shortest foo.mov` Now you can stream the `foo.mov` with this command: `ffmpeg -re -i foo.mov -c copy -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/STREAM_KEY`