# Ffmpeg Add image overlay on rmtp stream

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a m3u8 input and I convert it to a rmtp stream using this command:

```
ffmpeg -re -i "https://<url>.m3u8" -af asetpts=N/SR/TB -c:v copy -c:a aac -ar 44100 -ab 128k -ac 2 -f flv -flvflags no_duration_filesize -s 1920x1080 "rtmp://<url>"
```

But I would like to add my logo on the top right part of the stream, I didn't manage to do it, do someone know how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Try [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/watermarks)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735121/ffmpeg-continuously-stream-refreshing-image-to-rtmp